# Handle invalid UTF-16 characters with System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, utf-8, system.text.json

I'm trying deserialize string JSON into an object using `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer`. Occasionally the JSON that I'm trying to deserialize has invalid UTF-16 characters in it. For example, the character `\udcbf` is unable to be deserialized into a UTF-16 string. I've attempted to follow the guidelines [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#customize-character-encoding) for customizing character encoding, but this appears to exclusively apply to serialization.

[dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZMdVAu) to show the issue. Note that I'm using a JSON Encoder that supports all unicode characters from 0x0000 to 0xFFFF. This range encompasses 0xDCBF, which leads me to believe that the specified encoder is not used for deserializtion.

One thing that I did try to do was to write a custom converter to handle these invalid characters:

```cs
public class InvalidUtf16Converter : JsonConverter<string>
{
    public override string Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        try
        {
            return reader.GetString();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            var bytes = reader.ValueSpan;
            var sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.Length);
            foreach (var b in bytes)
                sb.Append(Convert.ToChar(b));
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        writer.WriteStringValue(value);
}
```

This approach *sort of* works (doesn't actually read it into a character) for string properties as seen [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LgENoT). Unfortunately, I sometimes have invalid UTF-16 characters in lists. In this case the provided converter does not work, as seen [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sLrwZL), since the converter is trying to convert a list into a string, which understandably breaks.

Is there a way to globally handle invalid UTF-16 characters in deserialization using `System.Text.Json`? If not, how would I write a converter similar to the one above for a list?

Comment: The JSON in your second fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/TGDJPO is not well-formed.  Your JSON looks like `{["Bar":"some value"]}` but you have transposed the object and array delimiters, it should be `[{"Bar":"some value"}]`.  Also in the second fiddle your data model is wrong, it should be `public class Foo
{
 public string Bar { get; set; }
}` and you need to deserialize to `List<Foo>`.  With those fixes your converter works, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/82GHW8.

Comment: Whoops. I also noticed that i didn't actually write the JSON in a way that accurately describes my situation. Deserializing into an object isn't possible since it's a list of strings, not a list of Bar. This is a better representation of my problem: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sLrwZL. I have edited my initial question.

Comment: To apply a converter to every item in a collection as it is deserialized, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67082032/3744182) to [System.Text.Json: How to apply a JsonConverter for a collection with a custom converter for the collection's items?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63419312/3744182).

Comment: The global way would be to add your `InvalidUtf16Converter` to `JsonSerializerOptions.Converters`. Note that your problem isn't just that `\udcbf` is an invalid UTF-16.  The problem is that `\udcbf` is a [low surrogate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U+D800_to_U+DFFF) that is apparently not paired with a high surrogate.  `Utf8JsonWriter` throws an exception for this pathology (and Json.NET replaces it with the fallback character 0xFFFD)