# System.Text.Json: How to apply a JsonConverter for a collection with a custom converter for the collection's items?

Tags: c#, json, collections, system.text.json

I have a class that I want to serialize to json. The class contains some trivially serialized members but the problem is that I have a list of objects that are from a cpp library (I have a C# has a wrapper for that library). I  can serialize and deserialize the library objects via a custom converter, but I have a list of them and I don't know what to do in this case. 
For simplicity I'll use the following example:

```cs
class Data
{
    // Some trivial members
    public List<LibraryObject> lst { get; private set; }
}

class LibraryObjectConverter : JsonConverter<LibraryObject>
{
    public override LibraryObject Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        // Implementation logic...
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, LibraryObject value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        // Implementation logic...
    }
}
```

If my class contained a known number of those objects I could just add the JsonConverter tag and use the default JsonSerivalizer for my class:

```cs
class Data
{
    // Some trivial members
    [JsonConverter(typeof(LibraryObjectConverter ))]
    public List<LibraryObject> lst { get; private set; }
}
```

Although because the class contains a list of the objects I cannot do that. 
Also I know I can use the following code, and It'll work:

```cs
var d = new Data();
var serializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions();
serializeOptions.Converters.Add(new LibraryObjectkConverter());
serializeOptions.WriteIndented = true;
Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(d, serializeOptions));
```

I would like a solution that doesn't require a JsonSerializerOptions, so I can use "The default converter". 
I prefer adding tags\logic rather than using the above solution for the ease of use for the consumers of code.

Comment: Forgot to mention, the main problem is with deserializing the data class. Serializing is easy: I can create a `ListLibraryObjectConverter` class and for each item in the list just write it and add the appropriate JsonTag to the declaration of the property. Reading is hard because the number of items is arbitrary and I would like to stick to the json conventions as much as possible.

Answer (score 10):

What you are looking for is the equivalent to Newtonsoft's [`JsonPropertyAttribute.ItemConverterType`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ItemConverterType.htm):

> Gets or sets the JsonConverter type used when serializing the property's collection items.

Unfortunately, as of .NET 5 there is no directly equivalent attribute for `System.Text.Json`.  Instead it will be necessary to introduce a `JsonConverter` [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) that serializes and deserializes collections and arrays using a specified encapsulated converter to serialize and deserialize the items.

The following `JsonConverterFactory` does exactly this:

```
public class ItemConverterDecorator<TItemConverter> : JsonConverterFactory where TItemConverter : JsonConverter, new()
{
    readonly TItemConverter itemConverter = new TItemConverter();

    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) => GetItemType(typeToConvert).ItemType is var itemType && itemType != null && itemConverter.CanConvert(itemType);

    public override JsonConverter CreateConverter(Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var (itemType, isArray, isSet) = GetItemType(typeToConvert);
        if (itemType == null)
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        if (isArray)
            return (JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ArrayItemConverterDecorator<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TItemConverter), itemType), new object [] { options, itemConverter })!;
        if (!typeToConvert.IsAbstract && !typeToConvert.IsInterface && typeToConvert.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null)
            return (JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ConcreteCollectionItemConverterDecorator<,,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TItemConverter), typeToConvert, typeToConvert, itemType), new object [] { options, itemConverter })!;
        if (isSet)
        {
            var setType = typeof(HashSet<>).MakeGenericType(itemType);
            if (typeToConvert.IsAssignableFrom(setType))
                return (JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ConcreteCollectionItemConverterDecorator<,,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TItemConverter), setType, typeToConvert, itemType), new object [] { options, itemConverter })!;
        }
        else
        {
            var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(itemType);
            if (typeToConvert.IsAssignableFrom(listType))
                return (JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ConcreteCollectionItemConverterDecorator<,,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TItemConverter), listType, typeToConvert, itemType), new object [] { options, itemConverter })!;
        }
        // OK it's not an array and we can't find a parameterless constructor for the type.  We can serialize, but not deserialize.
        return (JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(EnumerableItemConverterDecorator<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TItemConverter), typeToConvert, itemType), new object [] { options, itemConverter })!;
    }
    
    static (Type? ItemType, bool IsArray, bool isSet) GetItemType(Type type)
    {
        // Quick reject for performance
        // Dictionary is not implemented. 
        if (type.IsPrimitive || type == typeof(string) || typeof(IDictionary).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            return (null, false, false);
        if (type.IsArray)
            return type.GetArrayRank() == 1 ? (type.GetElementType(), true, false) : (null, false, false);
        Type? itemType = null;
        bool isSet = false;
        foreach (var iType in type.GetInterfacesAndSelf())
        {
            if (iType.IsGenericType)
            {
                var genType = iType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
                if (genType == typeof(ISet<>))
                {
                    isSet = true;
                }
                else if (genType == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
                {
                    var thisItemType = iType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                    if (itemType != null && itemType != thisItemType)
                        return (null, false, false); // type implements multiple enumerable types simultaneously. 
                    itemType = thisItemType;
                }
                else if (genType == typeof(IDictionary<,>))
                {
                    return (null, false, false); 
                }
            }
        }
        return (itemType, false, isSet);
    }
    
    abstract class CollectionItemConverterDecoratorBase<TEnumerable, TItem> : JsonConverter<TEnumerable> where TEnumerable : IEnumerable<TItem>
    {
        readonly JsonConverter<TItem> innerConverter;

        public CollectionItemConverterDecoratorBase(JsonSerializerOptions options, TItemConverter converter)
        {
            // Clone the incoming options and insert the item converter at the beginning of the clone.
            // Then if converter is actually a JsonConverterFactory (e.g. JsonStringEnumConverter) then the correct JsonConverter<T> will be manufactured or fetched.
            var modifiedOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions(options);
            modifiedOptions.Converters.Insert(0, converter);
            innerConverter = (JsonConverter<TItem>)modifiedOptions.GetConverter(typeof(TItem));
        }

        protected TCollection BaseRead<TCollection>(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) where TCollection : ICollection<TItem>, new()
        {
            if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartArray)
                throw new JsonException(); // Unexpected token type.  JsonTokenType.Null is handled by the framework, unless we set HandleNull => true (which we didn't).
            var list = new TCollection();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndArray)
                    break;
                var item = innerConverter.Read(ref reader, typeof(TItem), options);
                // TODO: optionally add checks to make sure innerConverter correctly advanced the reader to the end of the current token.
                list.Add(item!);
            }
            return list;
        }

        public sealed override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TEnumerable value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            writer.WriteStartArray();
            foreach (var item in value)
                innerConverter.Write(writer, item, options);
            writer.WriteEndArray();
        }
    }

    sealed class ArrayItemConverterDecorator<TItem> : CollectionItemConverterDecoratorBase<TItem [], TItem>
    {
        public ArrayItemConverterDecorator(JsonSerializerOptions options, TItemConverter converter) : base(options, converter) { }
        public override TItem [] Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) => BaseRead<List<TItem>>(ref reader, typeToConvert, options).ToArray();
    }

    sealed class ConcreteCollectionItemConverterDecorator<TCollection, TEnumerable, TItem> : CollectionItemConverterDecoratorBase<TEnumerable, TItem> 
        where TCollection : ICollection<TItem>, TEnumerable, new() 
        where TEnumerable : IEnumerable<TItem>
    {
        public ConcreteCollectionItemConverterDecorator(JsonSerializerOptions options, TItemConverter converter) : base(options, converter) { }
        public override TEnumerable Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) => BaseRead<TCollection>(ref reader, typeToConvert, options);
    }

    sealed class EnumerableItemConverterDecorator<TEnumerable, TItem> : CollectionItemConverterDecoratorBase<TEnumerable, TItem> where TEnumerable : IEnumerable<TItem>
    {
        public EnumerableItemConverterDecorator(JsonSerializerOptions options, TItemConverter converter) : base(options, converter) { }
        public override TEnumerable Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) => throw new NotImplementedException(string.Format("Deserialization is not implemented for type {0}", typeof(TEnumerable)));
    }
}

public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetInterfacesAndSelf(this Type type) => 
        (type ?? throw new ArgumentNullException()).IsInterface ? new[] { type }.Concat(type.GetInterfaces()) : type.GetInterfaces();
}
```

And then you would apply it to your model as follows:

```
class Data
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ItemConverterDecorator<LibraryObjectConverter>))]
    public List<LibraryObject> lst { get; set; }
}
```

Notes:

- Dictionary values are not supported by `ItemConverterDecorator`.  In contrast Newtonsoft's `ItemConverterType` property does support dictionary values.
- The converter does not support deserializing read-only collections.
- The code makes use of the [`JsonSerializerOptions` copy constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions__ctor_System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_) which was introduced in .NET 5.  If you are working in .NET Core 3.x you will need to replace `new JsonSerializerOptions(options)` with code to construct a fresh `JsonSerializerOptions` and manually copy each property.
- In your data model the `lst` property has a private setter:

  ```
  public List<LibraryObject> lst { get; private set; }
  ```

  Serialization of properties with private setters or getters is not supported in .NET Core 3.x.  In .NET 5 it is possible if you mark the property with [`[JsonInclude]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonincludeattribute?view=net-5.0)

  ```
  [JsonInclude]
  public List<LibraryObject> lst { get; private set; }
  ```

  See: [Non-public property accessors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-immutability?pivots=dotnet-5-0#non-public-property-accessors).

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1kYpfw).

Comment: How would you introduce a JsonConverter decorator using System.Text.Json?

Comment: @billy - the answer shows how to apply the converter to the model.  Or I suppose you could add it to `JsonSerializerOptions.Converters` e.g. like so `options.Converters.Add(new ItemConverterDecorator<MyCustomConverter>());`

Comment: oh, right, sorry, I thought it was json.net code.

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to create a `JsonConverter` implementation for reading and writing a collection of your custom type. Such a class might inherit `JsonConverter<Collection<MyType>>`, for example. However, if you already have a converter for `MyType` (i.e. `JsonConverter<MyType>)`, it would be nice to be able to reuse this type without having to duplicate its code or extract code from it into a shared class. This was my position.

I solved this by creating a generic class called `ListJsonConverter` that takes another `JsonConverter` as a type parameter, which it uses to read and write JSON arrays:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

public class ListJsonConverter<T, TConverter> : JsonConverter<IList<T>>
    where TConverter : JsonConverter<T>, new()
{
    private readonly JsonConverter<T> itemConverter = new TConverter();

    public override IList<T>? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartArray)
        {
            reader.Skip();
            return null;
        }

        var list = new List<T>();

        while (reader.Read() && reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.EndArray)
        {
            var item = this.itemConverter.Read(ref reader, typeof(T), options);
            if (item != null)
            {
                list.Add(item);
            }
        }

        return list;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, IList<T> value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStartArray();

        foreach (T item in value)
        {
            this.itemConverter.Write(writer, item, options);
        }

        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }
}
```

As an example, suppose we have class named `ImageJsonConverter` that inherits `JsonConverter<System.Drawing.Image>`, the `ListJsonConverter` type can be used with the `[JsonConverter]` attribute with a list of images, as follows:

```cs
[JsonConverter(typeof(ListJsonConverter<Image, ImageJsonConverter>))]
public IList<System.Drawing.Image> MyImageList { get; set; }
```

The `ImageJsonConverter` class is still available to use with single object:

```cs
[JsonConverter(typeof(ImageJsonConverter))]
public Image MyImage { get; set; }
```