# System.Text.Json - Serialize array of third-party Enum to array of strings

Tags: c#, .net, enums, .net-6.0, system.text.json

suppose I have the following DTO:

```
public class FooDto
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public DayOfWeek[] Days { get; set; }
}
```

In order to comply with the corresponding API, this DTO needs to serialize to json like this:

```
{
    "bar": "someString",
    "days": ["Monday", "Friday", "Sunday"]
}
```

Without any further actions the same DTO would serialize like this:

```
{
    "bar": "someString",
    "days": [1, 5, 0]
}
```

My Question:
Is there a way to use `System.Text.Json` in order to serialize an array of a third-party Enums like `System.DayOfWeek` as an array of it's string values? I am specifically **not** looking for a solution using json.net (Newtonsoft).

---

My Ideas that didn't work out:

- Using `[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]` does not work on arrays.
- In this case it's recommended to put the annotation directly above the Enum itself. This isn't possible since it's a thrid-party Enum.
- I can't simply create a "proxy" for `System.DayOfWeek` since Enums don't support inheritance.
- I could create my own `DayOfWeekDto` and write a mapper from `System.DayOfWeek` to `DayOfWeekDto` and vice versa, but this "solution" doesn't seem elegant at all.

Ideas for simple solutions that don't include Newtonsoft would be very welcome :)

Comment: You can apply `[JsonConverter(typeof(ItemConverterDecorator<JsonStringEnumConverter>))]` to `public DayOfWeek[] Days { get; set; }` where `ItemConverterDecorator<TConverter>` comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67082032/3744182) to [System.Text.Json: How to apply a JsonConverter for a collection with a custom converter for the collection's items?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63419312/3744182).  Demo fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9RPHoo.  In fact I think this is a duplicate, agree?

Comment: It certainly is yet another solution. However for this specific problem I do prefer both answers that were given here. I'm specifically asking for enums. The answers that I got here are not valid for the question you linked and are therefore destinct. At least in my opinion. I'm personally not looking for **any** solution, I'm always looking for the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a .NET API you can enable this behaviour globally like so:

```cs
services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter()));
```

However, if you are using the serializer specifically, you can use it like so:

```cs
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
{
    Converters = { new JsonStringEnumConverter() }
};

var x = JsonSerializer.Serialize(yourObj, options);
```

Comment: Thank you! In my search for a solution I didn't stumble upon the option to just enable it globally within the application. This also cleaned up the annotation usage for my other custom JsonConverters for DateTime, DateOnly and TimeOnly. And for unit testing I'm now using the second method that you provided. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this isn't an exactly answer to your question, more advice which others may disagree with.

Experience has shown me that using Enums with 3rd parties can cause a lot of trouble.

For example if the 3rd party returns a status on an object and then later adds a new status which isn't in your Enum when you try and deserialise it your system can just fall over (even if you would have just ignored it because it's not at the status you are interested in).

So what's the alternative?

Simple, create your Enum but don't use it for property types, instead set your property type to `string`. When assigning or comparing to your property type you would then use `MyEnum.SomeValue.ToString()`. Essentially your Enum just becomes a set of constants.

This has the added benefit that when you serialise you get the string value in the JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. However the enum in question was "System.DayOfWeek". I don't think anything is changing there any time soon. Simply using string instead of the enum itself would have been a solid solution. The solution of Mihail is more satisfying tho :D