# How to use a custom JsonConverter with IEnumerable (System.Text.Json)

Tags: c#, serialization, system.text.json

I am using a custom `System.Text.Json.JsonConverter` to serialize/deserialize instances of a complex enumeration type that can be represented as an integer value.

When applied to a simple property, JSON serialization works as expected, so I know that the JSON converter is functioning correctly.

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(MyEnumTypeConverter))]
public MyEnumType Member { get; set; }
```

However, if the same converter is used on a collection property, it fails (because the converter type does not match the property type).

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(MyEnumTypeConverter))]
public IEnumerable<MyEnumType> Members { get; set; }
```

I guess this behaviour is understandable, but I would expect that the JSON serializer would be able to infer that the members of an `IEnumerable<T>` should be serialized using the custom serializer for type `T`.

Is there a way to configure JSON serialization to use the same JSON converter when handling  the members of a collection? Or do I need to create a custom version of my JSON converter that supports `IEnumerable`? If the latter, can you please direct me to a code sample?

Comment: You're looking for something like Newtonsoft's `JsonPropertyAttribute.ItemConverterType`, but System.Text.Json doe not have anything like that.  Instead, you can use `ItemConverterDecorator<MyEnumTypeConverter>` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67082032/3744182) to [System.Text.Json: How to apply a JsonConverter for a collection with a custom converter for the collection's items?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63419312/3744182), which looks to be a duplicate.  Agree?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Yes, I agree, my question is a duplicate (although I did search before asking). Anyway, your suggestion solves my problem, thanks. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I checked, it works, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/C6Zaxw.

Comment: Thank you for creating the Fiddle. It perfectly solves my problem.