# Convert a Json Array to a List of Enum

Tags: c#, json, .net, enums

I have this json payload which is expected by my controller DTO named OperationSystemDTO

```
{
    "Status": true,
    "SubscriptionSystems": [
        "1", "3"
    ]
}
```

My Controller:

```
[HttpPost(nameof(Validate))]
[SwaggerOperation(nameof(Validate))]
public async Task<ActionResult> Validate([FromBody] OperationSystemDTO dto)
```

But when I POST this payload to my controller, my DTO is always `null`, and I noticed it's because of this list of enums. I tried to convert it with `[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]` annotation but no effect's at all.

```
public class OperationSystemDTO
{
    public bool Status {get; set;}
    public List<SubscriptionSystem> SubscriptionSystems {get; set;}
}

public enum SubscriptionSystem {
    SYS_1 = 1,
    SYS_2 = 2,
    SYS_3 = 3
}
```

Any idea of why this is happening?

Comment: Have you tried posting the numbers instead of strings with the enum numbers? May be JsonStringEnumConverter is expecting "SYS_1", "SYS_2",... instead of "1", "2",...

Comment: Yes I did, and it works, but the problem is, this payload is actually from an outsourced system, I cannot modify their post type @derloopkat

Comment: Which JSON serializer are you using?  System.Text.Json, Json.NET or something else?

Comment: `JsonStringEnumConverter` is from System.Text.Json which does not support applying converters directly to the items of a collection via attributes. If that is in fact the serializer you are using, as a workaround, you could apply `[JsonConverter(typeof(ItemConverterDecorator<JsonStringEnumConverter>))]` where `ItemConverterDecorator` comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67082032) to [System.Text.Json: How to apply a JsonConverter for a collection with a custom converter for the collection's items?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63419312).  Does that fully answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

The `[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]` attribute is to convert a single `enum` property.  For a collection of `enum`s, you can use `[JsonProperty(ItemConverterType=typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]` like below:

```
public class OperationSystemDTO
{
    public bool Status {get; set;}

    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
    public SubscriptionSystem SingleSubscriptionSystem { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
    public List<SubscriptionSystem> SubscriptionSystems {get; set;}
}
```