# Serializing custom types in a C# ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json, concurrentdictionary

With Newtonsoft, I can specify the following attribute on my CurrentDictionary defintion to indicate a custom serializer for my custom class: 'Saturation':

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "substances", ItemConverterType = typeof(SaturationJsonConverter))]
protected ConcurrentDictionary<string, Saturation> Substances { get; } = new();
```

Question: How can I mimic this behavior using System.Text.Json?

Comment: Your question is similar to the one from [System.Text.Json: How to apply a JsonConverter for a collection with a custom converter for the collection's items?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63419312/3744182), however the answers do not work for dictionaries, only non-dictionary collections.

Comment: Does make sense doing the serialization of a ConcurrentDictionary? I mean, the serialization is not an atomic process. Wouldn't be better to create a snapshot and serialize on that?